# Selenium WebdriverIO ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, selenium, centos, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Operating System: CentOS 8
NodeJS Version: v14.5.0
NPM Version: 6.14.5

When running my NodeJS program, which uses WebdriverIO to pull product info from sites like Target and BestBuy, it can't connect to a Selenium server from what I can tell. It throws an unhandled promise rejection warning like below.

```
ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:PORT
```

I have installed the Selenium standalone server, Chromedriver, WDIO-Standalone, and WebdriverIO. I tried running the Selenium standalone server jar on port 4444, as well as having the following driver function.

```
function driver(url, proxy) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        remote({
            runner: true,
            outputDir: __dirname,
            services: [
                ["selenium-standalone", {
                    logPath: "./selenium.out",
                    args: {
                        version: "4.0.0",
                        seleniumArgs: ["-host", "127.0.0.1", "-port", "4444"]
                    }
                }]
            ],
            capabilities: {
                browserName: "chrome",
                port: 4444,
                proxy: {
                    proxyType: "manual",
                    httpProxy: proxy.host + ":" + proxy.port
                },
                "goog:chromeOptions": {
                    args: [
                        "--headless", "--disable-gpu",
                        "user-agent=" + new UserAgent().toString()
                    ]
                }
            }
        }).then((browser) => sync(() => {
            browser.url(url);
            const $ = cheerio.load(browser.getPageSource());
            browser.deleteSession();
            resolve($)
        }));
    });
}
```

I can't seem to figure out the cause of the errors. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all I needed to do was add the `--no-sandbox` flag. Didn't even need to set the services and browser port, it simply failed to start Chrome as root withour `--no-sandbox`. Hope this helps anyone with this same issue.